# React useState is initially unchanged

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Take this piece of code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react' 

export function App() {

  let [isAdmin, setAdmin] = useState(false)

  const checkIfAdmin = async() => {
    setAdmin(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkIfAdmin()
  }, []);

  console.log(isAdmin)

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When console logging `isAdmin`, it comes out as false initially, but when checked again (such as in an `onClick()` event), it comes out as `true`. Why does it take 2 checks to finally output the desired result? How can I make it so that in `checkIfAdmin` the changes immediately take place, and `isAdmin` comes out as `true` on the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a function to `setAdmin()` to toggle in between states will immediately update the state variable.

```js
const checkIfAdmin = () => {
  setAdmin(isAdmin => !isAdmin)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting 2 console.logs, one that returns `false` and another that returns `true`. This is due to the way useEffect, and setState work.

When useEffect is used with an empty array as the second arg, it only runs once when the component mounts. And on the first mount of your component, `isAdmin` is initialized to `false`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    checkIfAdmin()
  }, []);
```

Once `setAdmin(true)` executes, it updates the dom, causing the component to render for a second time, with the `isAdmin` value being `true`

You can visualize how the dom is being updated by adding another console.log() in your useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('component is mounting...')
    checkIfAdmin();
  }, []);
```